# Redefining \@schapter cause a "perhaps a missing \item." error

Tags: table-of-contents, books

Here I want to automatically add string "toc" after the numbered chapter, and "notoc" after the unnumbered chapter, like this:

[image]

so I wrote this:

```tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\let\@@chapter\@chapter
\let\@@schapter\@schapter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\@@chapter[#1]{#2} toc}
% \def\@schapter#1{\@@schapter{#1} notoc}   % if uncomment, there will be a "missing \item" error 
% \apptocmd{\@schapter}{notoc}{}{}          % same behavior as above
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
    \chapter[option]{test}
    \chapter{test2}
    \chapter*{notoc}
\end{document}
```

I've learned the star-version and a non-star-version of `\chapter` are defined by `\@schapter` and `\@chapter`.

```tex
\newcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
```

So I want to just redefine these two commands to meet my demand.

After `\def\@chapter[#1]#2...`, everything works fine.

[image]

However after `\def\@schapter`, an error came out:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 ...sline {chapter}{\numberline {1}option}{3}{}
                                                  %
?
```

Why would this happen?

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to achieve by "add[ing] "toc" after the number[ed] chapter, and "notoc" after the unnumber[ed] chapter".

Comment: I updated my question with suggest by @Mico

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have “weird” error messages, one of the first things to do is to try setting

```
\errorcontextlines=1000
```

at the very beginning of the file. Upon running LaTeX again, you'll see, instead of just

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.1 ...sline {chapter}{\numberline {1}option}{3}{}
                                                  %
?
```

something more, namely

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

\GenericError  ...
                                                  \endgroup
\addpenalty ...roup \fi \fi \fi \else \@noitemerr
                                                  \fi
\l@chapter ...>\m@ne \addpenalty {-\@highpenalty }
                                                  \vskip 1.0em \@plus \p@ \s...
l.1 ...sline {chapter}{\numberline {1}option}{3}{}
                                                  %
?
```

So we see that `\@noitemerr` is issued when `\addpenalty` is being performed.

What's `\addpenalty`? We can see it in the LaTeX kernel

```
% latex.ltx, line 6540:
\def\addpenalty#1{%
  \ifvmode
    [<code that isn't relevant here>]
  \else
    \@noitemerr
  \fi}%
```

But where does `\addpenalty` come from? We have a clue, because it's apparent that LaTeX is doing something with the first line in the `.toc` file, in your case

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}option}{3}{}%
```

Since `\contentsline{chapter}` becomes `\l@chapter` and we see

```
% book.cls, line 618:
\newcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
```

we do recognize the tokens in the extended error message, so this is where things go wrong.

But what can cause this weird behavior? Well, it *must* be what you added to `\@schapter`.

Indeed, it is used when `\tableofcontents` is executed, because it contains `\chapter*{\contentsname...}`.

So your `notoc` is the cause of the problem? Why? Because it starts a paragraph and after this action `\contentsline{chapter}` is executed, leading to `\addpenalty` not in vertical mode.

I'm not sure what would be a reason to do those changes: are you perhaps trying to start chapters with some code for drop capitals or similar? Well, don't. You definitely would need to take precautions about not doing that action also on auxiliary chapters like the table of contents or the list of tables.

But do you have so many chapters that manually adding the styling is tedious?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After reading your answer, [source2e.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf) and [classes.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/classes.pdf), I understood why renewcommand `\@schapter` would lead to the error.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're employing the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package, I'd like to suggest that you make use of its `\apptocmd` macro to achieve your formatting objective -- in a way that doesn't involve redefining the existing contents of `\@chapter` and `\@schapter`. Specifically, I'd like to suggest you execute

```
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\@chapter}{toc\par}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@schapter}{notoc\par}{}{}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Could I ask why it didn't work without `\par`?

Comment: @Syvshc - Sorry, I don't know the answer to your follow-up question; maybe somebody else will post an answer that addresses that issue. At any rate, I think it's a good idea to employ an explicit `\par` directive, as otherwise the instruction `\chapter[option]{test}aaa` will output `tocaaa`, a single string -- probably not the desired outcome, is it?

Comment: @Syvshc: If you follow the chain of execution, `\tableofcontents` calls `\@starttoc` *after* you have set `notoc`. `\@starttoc` sets the ToC via repeated commands `\contentsline` (look in the `.toc` file). Each of these `\contentsline` entries expects you to be in vertical mode (since it issues `\addpenalty`), otherwise it throws a "no list item" error. Since you've set `notoc`, you're in horizontal mode, not vertical mode. That's why there's an error. Issuing an additional `\par` puts you in vertical mode and everything runs smoothly.

Comment: @Werner Sorry, I didn't understand. In my opinion,  `\@starttoc` inputs `main.toc`, but things in `main.toc` are the same as the correct compiling. Also, `\chapter*` didn't do anything with the `.toc` file, no things like `\contentsline`, why would it effect?

Comment: @Syvshc: Every item within the `.toc` should first check whether to break the page in order to continue on the next or not, similar to an `\item` in a list (like `itemize` or `enumerate`), even though the ToC is not set as a list. This is just because of the nature of a ToC - it is list-like and could span multiple pages (in general). To encourage a break-point, LaTeX inserts a *negative* penalty, but to do so, it has to also be in "vertical" mode, which it isn't due to setting `notoc`. The first `\contentsline` in `main.toc` (set by your first nonstarred `\chapter`) is where this happens.